# Android onCreate is called twice after backing out

Tags: android, kotlin, oncreate

I have a simple MainActivity and if the app is completely killed it looks like onCreate() is called once. If however I back out of the app so it still appears in the background, when I re-open it I get every log message twice. The weirdest part is if I generate a random number it is always the same in the 2 log messages.

I've tried adding android:LaunchMode="singleTop" (also singleInstance singleTask) in the activity and application tags of the Manifest.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val binding: ActivityMainBinding by lazy {
    ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
    setupViews()
    val data: Uri? = intent?.data
    DataHolder.getInstance().setItem(data)
    Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
    setupInjection()
    Timber.d("review nanoTime = ${System.nanoTime()}")
    Timber.d("review savedInstance = $savedInstanceState")
    Timber.d("review random = ${Random.nextInt()}")
}

override fun onPause() {
    Timber.d("review onPause()")
    super.onPause()
}

override fun onStop() {
    Timber.d("review onStop()")
    super.onStop()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    Timber.d("review onDestroy()")
    super.onDestroy()
    finish()
}

override fun onStart() {
    Timber.d("review onStart()")
    super.onStart()
}

override fun onRestart() {
    Timber.d("review onRestart()")
    super.onRestart()
}

override fun onResume() {
    Timber.d("review onResume()")
    super.onResume()
}
private fun setupInjection() {
    val appInjector = InjectorImpl(
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    )
    Injector.initialize(appInjector)
}

private fun setupViews() = binding.apply {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    navView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId){
            R.id.navigation_item_calculator -> {
                navController.navigate(BuilderFragmentDirections.actionBuilderToCalculator())
            }
            R.id.navigation_item_builder -> {
                navController.navigate(CalculatorFragmentDirections.actionCalculatorToBuilder())
            }
        }
        true
    }
    navView.setOnItemReselectedListener {  }
}
}
```

Here is a table of the log trace I get when I run the app on my phone from Android studio. Since the random numbers are the same I feel like this is actually a Logging bug in Android studio and the app isn't actually opened twice.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Realized my problem was with my logging library I used.

Timber was planting a new tree but wasn't uprooting old ones from being backed out so there were 2 instances of them. I fixed by putting a `Timber.uprootAll()` just before `Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())`

Comment: I suggest you plant your tree in the application class so it is guaranteed to happen only once and is available from absolutely everywhere. This is the intended way to use it.